# Load a file.txt into df in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I woul need help in order to transform a file content into a dataframe.

here is the file :

```
>OK0100087.1
0 375
376 750
751 1000
>OK0100088.1
0 87766
>OK0100089.1
0 66778
>OK0100090.1
0 47519
47520 73733
```

and the idea is that I would like to change this file content in a df such as :

```
Name           start end
OK0100087.1_0  0      375
OK0100087.1_1  376    750
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000
OK0100088.1    0      87766
OK0100089.1    0      66778
OK0100090.1_0  0      47519
OK0100090.1_1  47520  73733
```

where I add a _Number if several rows after the `>OK...number`

and where start are the first number and the end the last for each line.

does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```
txt <- readLines("foo.txt")
grp <- cumsum(grepl("^>", txt))
Reduce(rbind, by(txt, grp, function(x){
  name <- sub("^>", "", x[1])
  cbind(Name = if(length(x) > 2) paste(name, seq_along(x[-1])-1, sep = "_") else name,
        read.table(text = x[-1], col.names = c("start", "end")))
}))

#            Name start   end
# 1 OK0100087.1_0     0   375
# 2 OK0100087.1_1   376   750
# 3 OK0100087.1_2   751  1000
# 4   OK0100088.1     0 87766
# 5   OK0100089.1     0 66778
# 6 OK0100090.1_0     0 47519
# 7 OK0100090.1_1 47520 73733
```

Comment: Thanks but you add _0 for those who should not have _0 for exemple ```OK0100088.1``` and ```OK0100089.1``` @Darren Tsai

Answer (score 1):

Also using `data.table`

```
path <- "file.txt"

OUT <- fread(path, sep = ",", header = FALSE)
OUT[, 
    setNames(c(V1[1L], tstrsplit(V1[-1L], " ")), c("Name", "Start", "End")), 
    by = cumsum(grepl("^>", V1))
    ][, Name := sub(">", "", Name)
      ][, 
        Name := if (.N>1L) sprintf("%s_%d", Name, 1L:.N - 1L) else Name, 
        by = Name
        ][, !"cumsum"]

#             Name Start   End
# 1: OK0100087.1_0     0   375
# 2: OK0100087.1_1   376   750
# 3: OK0100087.1_2   751  1000
# 4:   OK0100088.1     0 87766
# 5:   OK0100089.1     0 66778
# 6: OK0100090.1_0     0 47519
# 7: OK0100090.1_1 47520 73733
```

Answer (score 0):

a data.table solution

I kept all in-between steps, so you can check what is actually done during the process..

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )

DT <- fread( 
text = ">OK0100087.1
0 375
376 750
751 1000
>OK0100088.1
0 87766
>OK0100089.1
0 66778
>OK0100090.1
0 47519
47520 73733", sep = "", header = FALSE)

#              V1
# 1: >OK0100087.1
# 2:        0 375
# 3:      376 750
# 4:     751 1000
# 5: >OK0100088.1
# 6:      0 87766
# 7: >OK0100089.1
# 8:      0 66778
# 9: >OK0100090.1
# 10:      0 47519
# 11:  47520 73733
```

**code**

```
#split to list
L <- split( DT, cumsum( grepl( "^>OK", DT$V1 ) ) )
#use first row as name
names(L) <- sapply( L, function(x) x[1] )
#drop first element from list, split values to column
L2 <- lapply( L, function(x) { 
  tmp <- x[-1]
  tmp[, c("start", "end") := tstrsplit( V1, " ") ][, V1 := NULL]
})
#bind together
ans <- rbindlist( L2, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "Name" )
#add_counter
ans[ ans[, if(.N>1) .I , by=.(Name)]$V1,
     Name := paste0( Name, "_", seq_len(.N) - 1 ), by = .(Name) ][]

#              Name start   end
# 1: >OK0100087.1_0     0   375
# 2: >OK0100087.1_1   376   750
# 3: >OK0100087.1_2   751  1000
# 4:   >OK0100088.1     0 87766
# 5:   >OK0100089.1     0 66778
# 6: >OK0100090.1_0     0 47519
# 7: >OK0100090.1_1 47520 73733
```

Comment: thank you but there is not the _number added for duplicated Name, do you have an idea how to add this one ?

Comment: Ok there is the _number but as for the previous solution ```OK0100088.1``` and ```OK0100089.1```should not have a _number since they are present only once.

Comment: updated the counter part... looks right to me now..